# Set the value of a datetimepicker on load

Tags: javascript, laravel, datetimepicker

After searching some days for a solution, I come to you.

I'm trying to automatically set the value of 2 bootstrap datetimepickers.

When I'm going on my view (I'm using laravel) I want my inputs to be already set to 2 days before for the first one, and 2 days after for the second.

But it's starting blank.

What I want when I arrive on the page :
[image]

What I get now :
[image]

Javascript code which init the dtp

```
if ($("#datetimepicker18").length) {
    $('#datetimepicker18').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fr',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        setDate: '{{ date_malus }}',
        autoclose: true,
        startView: 0,
        useCurrent: false,
    });
}

if ($("#datetimepicker19").length) {
    $('#datetimepicker19').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fr',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        autoclose: true,
        startView: 0,
        useCurrent: false,
    });
}
```

I tried to define the value with a laravel variable (carbon::now) but it's not working

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker18" value="{{ $date_malus }}" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker18" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
```

Does Someone already has encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your datetimepicker as you did and then do this:

```
$('#datetimepicker18').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
```